# Secure php web service ( with username and password)

Tags: php, web-services

How can I set a username and password for my webservice , like this one :
http://services.hanselandpetal.com/secure/flowers.json

Comment: That is basic HTTP Authentication. If you want to/can do it in your web server, and that web server is Apache, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are running apache then the first step will be to enable an authentication module (e.g. mod_auth_basic) which has to be done via your server's .conf file (The exact location depends on your apache installation and other configuration options. )

After this has been done create a file called .htaccess in the folder which contains your web services which you wish to secure, its contents should be along the lines of (Change the location of AuthUserFile to be where you wish to put the password file. ) it is reccomended that the file is not accessible from the web so in the example below I am assuming that your "web_root" is actually /var/www/htdocs/

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/etc/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Secure Files"
Require valid-user
```

After this has been performed you have to actually create the password file (replace mynewusername with the username you wish to add, and the location of the file with where you want to create it. but it must match the .htaccess location.)

```
htpasswd -c /var/www/etc/.htpasswd mynewusername
```

After the file has been created then you no longer need the "-c" argument and can simply call:

```
htpasswd /var/www/etc/.htpasswd myevennewerusername
```

Comment: What if this link suddenly disappears or the website no longer exists? It will render this *what is a comment really*, no longer valid. Link only answers are discouraged. Therefore, you should be adding the code from that page.